# Android: Blur listview behind a layout

Tags: android, layout, blur, uiblureffect

I have a listview and a layout that is in front of the listview. I want that layout to have as a background the blur of the listview that is in his back. Like in the image. The blur changes according to listview scrolling. How do I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This lib is what you need https://github.com/Dimezis/BlurView

```
<eightbitlab.com.blurview.BlurView
    android:id="@+id/blurView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >
    <!--anything below this view will be blured-->
</eightbitlab.com.blurview.BlurView>
```

in app.gradle defaultConfig

```
    renderscriptTargetApi 23
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

and in activity

```
    blurView = (BlurView) findViewById(R.id.blurView);

    final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    final View rootView = decorView.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    final Drawable windowBackground = decorView.getBackground();

    blurView.setupWith(rootView)
            .windowBackground(windowBackground)
            .blurAlgorithm(new RenderScriptBlur(this, true)) //Preferable algorithm, needs RenderScript support mode enabled
            .blurRadius(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Referred to this blog [post](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/blurring-images-part-1/)

```
private void blur(Bitmap bkg, View view, float radius) {
        Bitmap overlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                view.getMeasuredWidth(),
                view.getMeasuredHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(overlay);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bkg, -view.getLeft(),
                -view.getTop(), null);

        RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(this);

        Allocation overlayAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(
                rs, overlay);

        ScriptIntrinsicBlur blur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(
                rs, overlayAlloc.getElement());

        blur.setInput(overlayAlloc);

        blur.setRadius(radius);

        blur.forEach(overlayAlloc);

        overlayAlloc.copyTo(overlay);

        view.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(
                getResources(), overlay));

        rs.destroy();
    }
```

Comment: It'm not asking that Emin